# How do I increase the number in the JTextField every time I press the JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

```
    private void vote1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    int vote1 = 0;
    int vote2 = 0;
    if (koonchk.isSelected()){
        vote1++;
    koontf.setText(Integer.toString(vote1));

    }
    else if (baamchk.isSelected()){
        vote2++;
    baamtf.setText(Integer.toString(vote2));

    }


}
```

How do I increase the number in the `JTextField` every time I press the `JButton`?

[image: how do I increase the number in the jtextfield every time I press the jbutton]

Comment: Could you please reformat your code?

Comment: done, I have an image attached to it which you can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store `int vote1` and `vote2` outside of your method for `vote1ActionPerformed`, so that you dont reset the vote count to 0 every time.

That way its really easy to update it to a bigger number each time. For example this would work:

```
//Moved vote1/2 here outside of the method
static int vote1 = 0;
static int vote2 = 0;

    private void vote1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                      
        //We removed vote1 and vote2 from here and put them above
        if (koonchk.isSelected()){
        vote1++;
        koontf.setText(Integer.toString(vote1));
        }
        else if (baamchk.isSelected()){
        vote2++;
        baamtf.setText(Integer.toString(vote2));
        }
    }
```